# AdMob SDK 4.3.1 - I can't display banner

Tags: android

I have follow all the steps on AdMob tutorial, but when I run my application instead the banner there is "You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges"

My AndroidManifest is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="it.gmg.android.fpg"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" >

<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".FPGActivity" >
<intent-filter >
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>        

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


</manifest>
```

I think all is correct, why I cant display the banner?

Best regards

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899767/admob-error-in-eclipse-for-androidconfigchanges/7899849#7899849

Comment: Ok, my application need android 2.2, I also have installed all sdk versions, and I have added <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> to manifest, but nothing, doesn't work. Eclipse doesn't take my any error, only the application doesn't show the banner but a red message

Comment: I have the same problem. 4.3.1 does not accept screenSize config.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing some entries in the `configChanges` attribute of the Admob `AdActivity` -- see Google's description [here](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html). This may also cause you to change your build target. Read my detailed answer to the related quetsion [Admob implementation Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947165/admob-implementation-error/7951412#7951412).