# Admob implementation Error

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I got a Problem with implementing Admob into an App.

This is my main.xml:

> ```
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
> android:layout_width="fill_parent"
> android:layout_height="fill_parent"
> android:orientation="vertical" >
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/textView1"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="Large Text"
>     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
> <LinearLayout
>     android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:orientation="vertical" >
> </LinearLayout>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

and this is my Manifest:

> ```
> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> package="de.ollidiemaus.testmob"
> android:versionCode="1"
> android:versionName="1.0" >
> <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
> <application
>     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name" >
>     <activity
>         android:label="@string/app_name"
>         android:name=".TestAdmobActivity" >
>         <intent-filter >
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>         <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
>           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
> </application>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
> </manifest>
> ```

And finaly this is my Activity:

> ```
> public class TestAdmobActivity extends Activity {
> private AdView adView;
> /** Called when the activity is first created. */
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.main);
>     // Create the adView
> adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14ead58dc2a456");
> // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
> // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
> LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
> // Add the adView to it
> layout.addView(adView);
> // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
> adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());}    
> @Override
> public void onDestroy() {
>   adView.destroy();
>   super.onDestroy();
> }}
> ```

Now when i'll start the app in the AdView is an error called: "you must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges."

I used Android 4.0 so above 3.2 but it is not working.
I hope anyone could help me.

Comment: hmm this looks exactly like what i have. have you tried this on a lower api level?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem with getting the "you must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges." error message after integrating the latest AdMob SDK. Even though I have found this and the other two related discussions (see links at the bottom of this article) at StackOverflow, they didn't help me to solve the issue, as -- for me -- they did not differentiate clear enough between the `targetSdkVersion` attribute in the manifest and the build target. This answer describes what solved the issue for me and what caused trouble.

### Solution

The easiest part at first: you are missing a few flags in the `configChanges` attribute of the definition of the `AdActivity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. As shown in the [AdMob SDK Docs](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html) the definition needs to look like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

The second -- and more complicated part -- is related to the SDK target: The only solution that really seems to work is to use the SDK manager to install the SDK for at least Android 3.2 (API level 13). After you have installed this SDK version you need to configure your IDE to build your project using this SDK. The exact setting depends on the IDE you are using. In my case it is IntelliJ IDEA and there you will find the option in the project settings on the *Project* page below the headline *Project SDK*.

You should also adjust the `target` property in your project's `project.properties`. This is at least important if you are building your release using ANT. The line should look like this:

```
target=android-13
```

**The configuration above alone does the trick. There are *no* changes required to the `<uses-sdk>` element in the AndroidManifest. Read the pitfalls below to learn why this may cause trouble.**

### Explanation

The build target and the `<uses-sdk>` elements have completely different scopes.

The **build target** is evaluated *only* at build time by your build tools to determine which version of the SDK tools on your system should be used to build your app. The newer the SDK the more API features does it know. Out of whatever reason Google forces us to specify some `configChanges` which aren't available before API level 13 and so we need to build our app using at least the SDK tools 13 because a previous version of the SDK tools does not know these new `configChanges` and will report an error. At runtime the build target does not have any meaning and Android will ignore all elements (e.g. in `configChanges`) which it does not know.

The **targetSdkVersion** element specified on the `<uses-sdk>` element in the android manifest in contrast is *only* evaluated at run time -- *not* at compile time. In fact you can specify any value you want here without the compiler changing anything or bringing up an error message. This is why changing this attribute does not help us to solve our AdMob problem. On the other hand at runtime the attribute may be evaluated by android to support some compatibility features for apps which have been build for older android versions. See the pitfalls section below to see a topic which caused trouble for me.

### Pitfalls

- **Do *not* change set `targetSdkVersion` to a higher version if you are not able to test your app on this android version:** Because I have misunderstood the existing answers regarding this admob topic I have also set the `android:targetSdkVersion` attribute of the `<uses-sdk>` element to API level 13 in my app which caused a fatal side effect: As Android 3 thought my app would natively support honeycomb, it did no longer show the menu button in the soft button bar at the bottom border and as my app hides the native title bar to show it's own implementation the user did not have any possibility to access the menu any more on honeycomb. So for me leaving the `targetSdkVersion` at level `10` helped to bring back the menu button and worked fine.
- **Handling backward compatibility to older APIs which may be lost in SDK tools 13:** OK, so I have set my build process to use the SDK tools 13 and my `targetSdkVersion` to 10 and everything should be fine, right? Unfortunately not! The reason is, that my app is compatible downwards to Android 1.5 (API level 3) as this still makes up about 5% of my users. Unfortunately after setting the build target to 13 some parts of my code did not compile any more as they referenced deprecated methods which were supported until SDK tools 10 but no longer starting with SDK tools 11 (e.g. `Service.setForeground`).

The basics how to handle backwards compatibility are described [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html) -- but this article does not describe how to call deprecated methods which are no longer available as they will cause a compiler error. I solved this by creating a new library project used by my app. For this library project I have set the build target back to 10 which will cause it to be compiled using the SDK tools 10 which still know about the android deprecated API I am using. My app then calls helper methods from this compatibility library and so I can compile my app with a newer target SDK.

---

### Related Topics

Here the list of the other related discussions I have found:

- [AdMob can't display ads because of configChanges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7902121/280384)
- [AdMob SDK 4.3.1 - I can't display banner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7901018/280384)

Comment: but my build target is already Android 4.0
but its still not working

Comment: does your `AndroidManifest.xml` still look as shown in your original post? If yes, then you are still missing some flags in the `configChanges` attribute of the `AdActivity` definition. The full list as specified by the [AdMob SDK docs](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html) is `keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize`.

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'kkeyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreâ€Œâ€‹enSize'). AndroidManifest.xml /Test Admob 

This is the error which i got by adding the flags...

Comment: your string has been messed up: Two 'k's at the start and a lot of crap at the end ;-) Ensure that you really have the string shown in the SDK docu. If it still brings a compile error, then I bet that you have downloaded the latest android SDK, but didn't really manage to tell your IDE to really use this latest SDK's tools.

Comment: ok that happened by copy and paste xD
i copy it from the SDK
and then i'll reinstalled the Sdk and it really worked but only in 4.0 emulator on my real Desire Z on 2.3.7 the ad dont show up but no more error

Comment: I upgraded Eclipse from Galileo to Indigo and had this exact problem when I was setting up the new IDE.  I didn't understand the scope difference between "build target" and "uses sdk" and couldn't for the life of me figure out what was generating the error.  I knew that version 13 was required as per the admobs instructions, but since my phone is version 10 I had though it wouldn't have let me run it.  Thanks for not just the fix to get the admobs banners working again, but for the detailed explanation about what was very confusing.

Comment: I am getting admob in bottom centre of the screen of device. How can i change that position to right top?

Answer (score 1):

My solution to a similar case was to use

`<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" />`

or just use android:targetSdkVersion= under 13

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set the following permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Then admob can assess the internet and also not show the ad when it has no internet connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Have you also set your build target to be higher than Android 3.2, i.e. in default.properties set target higher than android-13? Also make sure that you're using the latest version of the SDK.

PS! Don't expose your device ID to the public.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here, very few phones have Android versions of 3.x.x or higher installed

http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

Why would anybody want to compile their app to something few phones can handle?  Either I am misunderstanding something or I will need to find some other ad company that doesn't require a newer Android version.

Answer (score 0):

Above error occurs when you use the library GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.3.1.jar.
I've been that error and I've found [this demo from Google](http://code.google.com/intl/vi/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html).
I've replaced lib 4.3.1 by 4.0.3 in this demo and it runs OK.

Answer (score 0):

if you use AndroidStudio and Gradle, you must also update the build.gradle file like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 3
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
...
```