# How to tell eclipse to build using a specific SDK

Tags: android, eclipse

I have the exact same problem as the guy who wrote [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947165/admob-implementation-error) question. The answer involved instructing the IDE (in my case eclipse) to "you need to configure your IDE to build your project using this SDK". So my question is - how do I instruct eclipse to build using a specific SDK? (I already have a variety of different SDKs installed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on your project root in the package explorer. Click on the "properties" item. In the properties window on the left click "Android", in the right pane choose your SDK. Click apply and Ok.

And of course don't forget to set this line(after the `</application>`) accordingly in your AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="11"></uses-sdk>
```

Comment: What made you choose 5 & 11 specifically?

Comment: My app is able to run on Android 2.O(api 5) because I don't use any api call that was introduced later. And so far I only tested it on devices up to Android 3.0(api 11). Refer to this page : http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html

Answer (score 0):

right click on the project in the package explorer and select properties
then pick "Android" 
A List of "Project Build Targets" appears, alter to the target version required

Then run to install to a connected hardware device or configured emulator

Answer (score 0):

Target SDK can be configured on a project in the following way:

1. Right click on the Android project in Eclipse
2. Select `Properties`
3. Choose `Android` on the left panel
4. On right select the target SDK of your choice

Or set targetSDK(API level) in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```