# Getting error for Android Apps in Admob implementation

Tags: android, admob

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Admob implementation Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947165/admob-implementation-error)

Foe AdMob, I am using GoogleAdmobAdsSdk-4.3.1.jar file.
I am getting below error in the ads area of my HTC device
"You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges."

But I have added this configChanges in AndroidManifest file as:

```
<activity
android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" />
```

So what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 4.3.1, your activity would probably need have some extra items under configChanges as below:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Also, if you do this and you don't have the target set in your project.properties file (probably need to set `target=android-13` or higher assuming you have an Android SDK of 3.2 or higher).

Found this info in a blog post [here](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/11/migrating-to-v431-of-admob-sdk-for.html).

Comment: Thanks @RajPara. I have updated to Android 3.2 and add the configChanges in the manifeast file. But Now I am unable to show the ads. But previously I am seeing the frame for ads with error text. But now there is no frame for ads.

Comment: Are you sure you've declared your AdView correctly? You can check out http://code.google.com/intl/da/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html

Comment: Below is the AdView:
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/layoutAds"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adUnitId="a14f415121b6309"
            adsadSize="BANNER"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

Comment: Are you getting anything back from your logcat output in the console when you run your app?