# Android 2.3 admob error

Tags: android, admob

Im trying to put an admob on one of my activities and i did everything instructed and I keep getting this error when i run the code "You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges, when i use all the code i get a build error..(I have all the permissions needed declared as well)

Here is my android manifest code for the ad:

```
<activity 
 android:name = "com.google.ads.AdActivity"
 android:configChanges= "keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode">
</activity>
```

Here is my xml code for the activity i want it displayed on:

```
    <com.google.ads.AdView
   android:layout_gravity=""
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="MY_PRIVATE_ID"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:adSize = "BANNER" />
```

Can someone give me a clear and simple answer as to what I need to do in order to get this running, I also downloaded android 3.2, but I dont know how to configure in the build path of my existng android 2.3 project

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on which version of the jar file you are using.

For **GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.1.1.jar** try

```
android:configChanges= "keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

and for **GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.1.3.jar** try

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

Comment: i know, when im using 4.1.3 jar.. i dont know how to get the 4.1.1 jar, and when i use the bottom code you have for 4.3.1 i get a build error unless i project.properties to 13, but the the whole project gets an error even if i clean it..

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947165/admob-implementation-error). There's an awesome explanation given there.