# Google ADs(ADmobs) requires APi level 4.0 Android

Tags: android, admob

I am working on Admobs . I downloaded code from this  [Admobs site](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals)  now in manifest file it is declare that for Ad view Activity it should use these config changes:

> android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"

which is available in 4.0 and above in android. but my app built requires 3.0 api level and above so in 3.0 till 3.2 i can't use these config settings so when i use:

> android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode

it gives error:

> you must have adActivity declared in manifest with config changes

And ads not shown after this any help would be appriciated

Comment: [This looks to be a pretty thorough solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7951412/1270789), and incidentally the first hit on Google for the error message.

Comment: @KenY-N thankyou so much great help indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this helps you, i have facing same issue but and solve as following way,in Your `Manifest` files declare like, change `minSdkVersion` `targetSdkVersion` as require.

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="13" />


<activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```