# AdMob error: "You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges"

Tags: android, error-handling, admob

I have looked at similar questions and did all the suggestions and I am still getting this message on my phone: "You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges".

Here is what I have in the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="..." android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name"   android:allowBackup="true">
<activity android:name="..." android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode"/>    
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="..." />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

Is there anything else that I should do?
Please note: I have looked at other similar questions, and none of the answers solves my problem.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are missing quite a few (well, just the two really) in those attributes. `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Admob implementation Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947165/admob-implementation-error)

Comment: @IceMAN I tried adding `screenSize|smallestScreenSize` but now I get error.

Comment: Here is the error I get: `error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|
 screenSize|smallestScreenSize').`

Comment: Guys I know this is a similar question to other questions, but the solutions for those did not resolve my problem.

Comment: you have to set your project build target to Android 3.2 or higher

Comment: set target in default.properties to android-13

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your manifest to

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

also,

you have to set your project build target to `Android 3.2` or higher .

**Note:**

Don't forget these two permissions in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Refer [this](http://jmsliu.com/209/add-google-admob-in-android-application.html) tutorial

Read [documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/)

Comment: As soon as I add: `screenSize|smallestScreenSize` I get error.

Comment: you didn't follow my answer, see configChanges. You need to have all the 7 items

Comment: as I said above when I add `screenSize|smallestScreenSize` I get error. I have reported the error I get above.

Comment: right click on the project folder in eclipse->properties->choose android->choose firmware 3.2 or higher

Comment: Thanks, I did that and error is gone but I also don't see any Ad block on the screen now. Also my device is Android 2.3.4, is that Ok that I choose Android 4.2.2 in the properties?

Comment: my sdk is the latest, I meant the phone that I have has Android 2.3.4. Will that still work? why I don't see the Ad banner now?

Comment: sorry. I don't know about that, are you able to see Ad banner in emulator?

Comment: SO, the problem may be in your phone because of Android 2.3.4, but i'm not sure about this

Comment: So my build target cannot be lower than 3.2?

Comment: Yes, don't forget. uiMode supported in 3.2

Comment: This means AdMob is not going to work for versions below 3.2?

Comment: As far i know, yes. I'm always set the latest versions for all the projects. So i didn't faced this issue