# I keep getting configChanges: String types not allowed error. Even with target API set to 13

Tags: android, admob

```
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value
    'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize').
```

Here is all my relevant code.

In the manifest:

```
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="13"

    android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout
        |uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

SOLVED!!!
   The problem was the break in the tags on configChanges. They needed to be all on one line together. Do not split the line for readability, leave it together.

Comment: Have you wrapped `android:name` and `android:configChanges` in an `<activity>` tag?

Comment: yes i did. Sorry for not showing the full code there.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208729/error-string-types-not-allowed-at-androidconfigchanges-in-manifest-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015972/android-admob-integration-issue-string-types-not-allowed

Comment: I added the line break for readability, removing that has solved my error. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem, but I was building my app with api 8. I also had api 13 as minimum sdk version. This is how to get it working: right click on your project>properties>android>choose android 3.2 or higher. This worked for me

Comment: Yes, I was having a mother of a time with everything correct.  This is what I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Even if your target is 13, I guess this will not work on devices with api less than 13 because the changed value is not just a `TAG` in the manifest, but it is a `VALUE` of a `TAG`. Therefore, the system will parse these values regardless of its api and will throw an exception when it finds an unknown `VALUE`.

To solve this, you will have to build the project twice: for api < 13 and for api >=13.

Correct me if I am mistaken (:

Comment: Admob is suppose to work on all devices with android 1.6(or 1.5, cant remember) and up. But it can only be built with api 13 and up. I've seen this same question a lot and everyone else gets it working just by changing the target api to 13 or higher.

Comment: Remove `smallestScreenSize` & `screenSize` & `orientation` from the 'android:configChanges'

Comment: If I do that then my application crashes and says those three are needed in configChanges.

Comment: So your minSdkVersion must be 13

Comment: If you read my code you will see that it is in fact set to 13.

Comment: and if i build against api level 15 the error on configChanges goes away but then my R.java will not generate, causing tons of errors in my java file