# Adding Admob code to Android giving error: You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest, admob

I'm trying to implement my first ads with Admob. I've read the other posts that seems to be helpful, as well as this:
[AdMob can't display ads because of configChanges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902121/admob-cant-display-ads-because-of-configchanges)

So I've set the project build target to Android 4.0 (API 14). I've also added this is the project.properties.

```
# Project target.
target=android-14
```

Then I've included these lines in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

I've also added to required code to display the ad in my activity class.
(Like descirbed here: http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html)

The problem is that when I run this code, the ad space is showed but with only message that says:

```
 "You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges".
```

The same thing is printed out on the logcat.

Am I ignoring something here? Could anyone with point me some other way?

Comment: Thanks, but that is the one I've already linked to in my post...

Comment: Which admob version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Set your Build Target to latest you have (>=4) it will work.
You can still have minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion as you like.

The ad will appear after a while, be patient :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the admob sdk jar to the project?