# Admob with version 4.0 only?

Tags: android

I am looking at introducing admob to my application which is developed in version 2.1 so it can support all devices. However I think that I just read that admob will not work for any devices that are prior to 3.2 or 4(cant remember) and that the most recent admob SDK should be downloaded or it will not work.

Can you confirm my undertsanding and if so what should I do to make ti run on olderversions?
Thank you

Comment: Similar question has been asked before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902121/admob-cant-display-ads-because-of-configchanges

Comment: Great Link! Thanks XiaoChuan. But the question is compiling in 3.2 doesnt mean it needs 3.2?thanks

Comment: Hmm...you can try to compile your app against Android 3.2 but specify the MinSDK in the app manifest to be at 2.1's api level. These means you cannot use any feature that Android 3.2 have and 2.1 does not. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to target version 3.2 or higher but it can still work on older versions !
I do so in my apps TargetVersion=4.0.3
                    MinimumVersion=1.6
and then it works well on all platforms !!