# eclipse displays error in the manifest

Tags: android

> I am using

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

> in the manifest. But eclipse gives me an error "string types not allowed"
>   so what is missing from my eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post:

[Admob Error in Eclipse for android:configChanges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899767/admob-error-in-eclipse-for-androidconfigchanges)

maybe you have a similar problem. This changes are not supported under apilevel 2.1