# Running from Eclipse on devices lower than project's target API version

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

The latest version of AdMob SDK (the only one available to download) requires `target=android-14` in the project's properties. This doesn't prevent one from running the app on lower versions of the platform (provided they are compatible with `minSdkVersion`), but Eclipse "Run" menu filters out all devices (virtual and real) with platform version less then `target`. Typical scenario

- `minSdkVersion` set to Android 2.1 (API 7)
- `target` set to ICS (API 14), otherwise you won't be able to compile the project because there are errors in the manifest, due to new values for `configChanges` ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899767/admob-error-in-eclipse-for-androidconfigchanges))

You can run the app on any device >= Eclair **only** with the command line, because Eclipse filters out any device < 14. This makes it difficult to test on emulators. I use latest version of ADT (r19) and the Eclipse plugin (18.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it really filter them out, or is there just a red `X` next to them?  You can still click on those devices to run the app.  It's annoying that Eclipse complains about your emulator/device being lower than the target version.

FYI, the SDK requires a minimum of `target=android-13` to support the `screenSize|smallestScreenSize` configChanges.

Comment: They are filtered out. The red X appears when I switch `target` back to some value, then the Eclipse plugin incostistently shows that icon. But when I restart Eclipse (or something gets recompiled) the devices are not available. You are right about the configChanges, but if you don't define them in the manifest Admob complains at runtime

Comment: Yes, AdMob requires `<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>` in order to run, and as mentioned in my answer, the last two config changes require `target=android-13` or higher in project.properties.  Of course, in the manifest you can change your `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to be whatever you want.  The red X for all devices where it's version is lower than the project.properties version.  Devices lower than the minSdkVersion won't run the app.

Comment: In the past I've issues where Eclipse just doesn't recognize an emulator that I have running.  When that happened I ran adb kill-server (and adb start-server if necessary), and then Eclipse picked up the running emulator.

Comment: If you manually choose the device, then all compatible devices appear (along with the red "X", but this doesn't matter), but it doesn't work with automatic run. I thing AdMob could have done better with this, since most of the devices still run 2.2

Comment: Good point, I forgot to mention that I was running the manual option.