# AdMob+Android: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|key

Tags: android, titanium, admob

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Admob Error in Eclipse for android:configChanges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899767/admob-error-in-eclipse-for-androidconfigchanges)

I'm trying to get AdMob to work in my Android app. I'm making a new question because I already followed the advice of previous threads.

I'm using Appcelerator Titanium.

- Android API is set to 4.0.3 in Run Configurations inside Titanium.
- Tool API Level: `<tool-api-level>16</tool-api-level>`
- Activity: `<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>`
- I've ran a Clean on my project

Getting this error:

```
[ERROR] /Users/Path/build/android/AndroidManifest.xml:13: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize').
```

What am I doing wrong/What is causing this? Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899767/admob-error-in-eclipse-for-androidconfigchanges

Comment: Kazekage, as noted, I've followed that thread and the guidelines within it, but I still get this error.

Answer (score 6):

In the  tag in AndroidManifest, use this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
```

Of course, change the minSdkVersion to whatever you're using now.

Also, set the target to 17 on project.properties, then save, fix project properties and clean.

EDIT: Changed targetSdkVersion and target on project.properties from 15 to 17. Just try to target the latest version available.

Comment: I have done that, I still get the error.

Comment: i have also done that and still the same error .....

Comment: You can also try Help -> About ->Installation History, and change it to a previous workstation