# Error string types not allowed at android:configChanges in manifest file

Tags: android

Here is my manifest file which shows error string types not allowed at android:configChanges please help me in rectification of the error.
below is my manifest file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ifahja.banner"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyBannerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>


    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


</manifest>
```

Comment: What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: Error in Eclipse for android:configChanges

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899767/admob-error-in-eclipse-for-androidconfigchanges

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

`screenSize` & `smallestScreenSize` attributes are not available in SDK 10.They are been introduced in API level 13.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

Comment: IE, change project target to API level 13 or above.

Comment: Project > Properties > Android > Change 'Project Build Target' to above 3.2.

Comment: But... that means my app will not work in Gingerbread, right?:-(

Comment: This does not mean you will loose compatibility with gingerbread @Yavierre. Target SDK is just the compiler that runs on your code. The "minimum SDK level" is the furtherest back your app will be compatible with.

Answer (score 6):

- Make sure you have the latest copy of the Android SDK and that you're
  compiling against at least Android v3.2 (set target in
  project.properties to android-13).
- The Google Mobile Ads SDK for Android requires a run-time of Android 2.3 or later (set
  android:minSdkVersion to at least 9 in your AndroidManifest.xml).
  This means you can develop with the latest version of the Android SDK
  and your app will still run on an earlier Android version (2.3
  minimum).