# AndroidManifest.xml:47: error: Error: String types not allowed

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Hi here is the full error I get in eclipse while loading an Android Application.

> AndroidManifest.xml:56: error: Error: String types not allowed (at
>   'configChanges' with value 'orientation|screenSize').

Here is the xml line in question

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276356/error-string-types-not-allowed-at-configchanges-with-value-keyboardkeyboa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **minSdkVersion should be 13**  .

Set this .I hope it will works .

For details please check below Links .

> [Error string types not allowed at android:configChanges in manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208729/error-string-types-not-allowed-at-androidconfigchanges-in-manifest-file)
>
> ["Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|keyboardHidden| orien"... in AndroidManifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276356/error-string-types-not-allowed-at-configchanges-with-value-keyboardkeyboa)