# Not able to integrate mobvista SDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, admob

Hi my androidmanifestxml is as below,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.genedevelopers.shootthedevil"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <!-- MobvistaSDK *begin* -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <!-- For Interactive Ad (Optional) -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <!-- MobvistaSDK *end* -->
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.genedevelopers.shootthedevil.MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_menu"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- MobvistaSDK *begin* -->
        <activity android:name="com.mobvista.sdk.core.ad.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>

        <!-- For admob -->
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

        <!-- For mobfox -->
        <activity android:name="com.adsdk.sdk.banner.InAppWebView"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

        <activity android:name="com.adsdk.sdk.mraid.MraidBrowser"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

        <!-- For startapp -->
        <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.list3d.List3DActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />

        <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.AppWallActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <!-- MobvistaSDK *end* -->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

i am getting the error,
 * What went wrong: Execution failed for task :shootTheDevil:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>               C:\Users\krazy\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I

```
C:\Users\krazy\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar -M D:\AndroidStudioProject\shootTheDevil\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S D:\AndroidStudioProject\shootTheDevil\build\intermediates\res\debug -A D:\AndroidStudioProject\shootTheDevil\build\intermediates\assets\debug -m -J D:\AndroidStudioProject\shootTheDevil\build\generated\source\r\debug -F D:\AndroidStudioProject\shootTheDevil\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.genedevelopers.shootthedevil -0 apk
        Error Code:
            1
        Output:
            D:\AndroidStudioProject\shootTheDevil\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:46: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize').
            D:\AndroidStudioProject\shootTheDevil\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:53: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize').
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution, the compileSdkVersion in build.gradle file shouldbe >13.  so we can retain
minSdkVersion 9
targetSdkVersion 15
now its working fine thanku

Answer (score 1):

### Whats your logcat throws

> D:\AndroidStudioProject\shootTheDevil\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:46:
>   error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value
>   'orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize').
>               D:\AndroidStudioProject\shootTheDevil\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:53:
>   error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value
>   'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize').

**screenSize and smallestScreenSize** attributes are not available in `SDK 9`. Introduced in API level ***13***.

```
android:minSdkVersion="13"
```

1. [Error string types not allowed at android:configChanges in manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208729/error-string-types-not-allowed-at-androidconfigchanges-in-manifest-file)

Comment: so i need to change minSdk to 13? if i do that will the app works in lower versions of android like gingerbeard and all?

Comment: @vinu yes .switch to 13

Comment: @vinu No .`gingerbeard(2.3) api 9`