# Error:(121, 36) String types not allowed (at 'configChanges'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-build

I have imported the sample for "Google Plus " from extras and I am facing the issue while building the project.

Could you please assist me to resolve this ?

[image]

Comment: Add this to your manifest if not already added: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` and then restart your `Studio`. It might just be a bug in `Studio`. Also, just to confirm the problem is with `Studio`, try building your application from the command prompt or terminal.. (gradle build)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

These attributes were introduced in API level 13, so make sure your minSdkVersion is equal to 13 or higher. The same applies to your compileSdkVersion.

See also: [Error string types not allowed at android:configChanges in manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208729/error-string-types-not-allowed-at-androidconfigchanges-in-manifest-file)