# android admob not working

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, admob

Hi i tried to include ads in my app !!!

I added external jars added permissions , activity as from the tutorials but there is a problem when i added the ad in the layout

it shows this error

"java.lang.NullPointerException"

I am using Min sdk version Android 2.3.3

Target 2.3.3

API level: 10

Project gets build but does not open !!!!

Below is my code:

```
enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.rhstudioss.adaps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.rhstudioss.adaps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="MyID"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me to solve the problem thankssss :-)

Comment: Can you post your whole log cat please

Comment: @jcw i cant able to post it .

Comment: can u give me your mail id @jcw so that i will send it in notepad. ????

Comment: @jcw everything works fine until i add the ad in the layout.

Comment: After i add the ad xml layout . java.lang.NullPointerException problem comes.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things I have noticed in your code:

*First*, the target SDK should be at least API 13 (Ref. Link: [Admob Error in Eclipse for android:configChanges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899767/admob-error-in-eclipse-for-androidconfigchanges))

Change it look like this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="13"/>
```

*Second*, this part in your code posted in the OP:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>
```

should be:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
</activity>
```

**UPDATE**

For more reference, read up on [**this**](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/) link. Once you have the site open, change to the **Android** tab (you will on iOS by default)

Comment: Hi your manifest code shows the error : "String types not allowed"

Comment: @aiohanar: that is because the target SDK is not set to API 13 and above. Check the reference link I had added to the post.

Comment: I have changed still the problem exists "String types not allowed"

Comment: @aiohanar: None actually. I seem to have missed your earlier comment. But one of the above suggestions should have worked for you. :-(

Answer (score 0):

After you've properly positioned your adView, try this out.

Step 1:
- Right click on your project.
- Locate the new Google_Admob_Jar file at C:\Users\YOURNAME\android-sdks\extras\google\admob_ads_sdk, if you have the latest version.
- Click OK

Step 2:
 
- Right click on your project.
- Properties-> Java_Build_Path-> Order_and_Export.
- Select the Google_Admob_Jar.
- Click ok
Hope it helps :)

Comment: the problem is not the ad is getting loaded the problem is that whenever i included the ad the application stops working and the reason is "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: the problem comes only after i add ad in xml layout. the application starts without the ad. But when i include the ad in xml the problem arises