# Admob is not able to load any ads

Tags: android, xml, admob

Admob is not able to load ads into my app. I have been waiting for a while, and still there is no ad.

```
   <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="pub-||||||||||||||||" \\ blanked out. 
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, 20080411413fc082"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

My Manifest

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation
|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

LogCAT

```
10-06 20:43:28.187: W/Ads(11465): Invalid unknown request error: Cannot determine request type. Is your ad unit id correct?
10-06 20:38:52.937: E/ActivityThread(11465): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
```

Image

Image to show that I have admob jar in libs.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any error in logcat?

Comment: question updated with logcat ... and image to prove I have jar in lib

Comment: It's a wrong adUnitId, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a wrong value in `adUnitId`. It's not your publisher ID, it's a separate number called Ad Unit ID.

In Admob, go to Monetise, All Apps, and expand "View code integration instructions" for your app. If it's not there, you have to add your app.

Comment: I just changed my adUnitId.  But there is still no ad. I have heard you have to hours for ads to show in app, is that right?

Comment: It may take some time to get the first ad, that's what admob said. But I got it in a few minutes.

Comment: It worked my man, how about banner id to change according to device. Any idea for that. I want banner Id to show across screen

Comment: You could use different layouts based on the device?

Comment: Yea, i thought the same. Thanks a lot.

Comment: yes, you are right its not a Publisher ID, its the unique id of each application

Answer (score 1):

finally this problem resolved for me .....
downgrade from 19 to 17 and upgrade from 3 to 13 like this :

```
android:minSdkVersion="13"
android:targetSdkVersion="17"
```

do more tests by the adv you get the ads

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget permissions ?

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

- the target SDK should be at least API 13

Comment: permission is there, android: minSdkVersion="11" and android:targetSdkVersion="18"

Comment: where did you find your adUnitId ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899767/admob-error-in-eclipse-for-androidconfigchanges (for Szymon about api lvl)

Comment: @Szymon, you're saying my minSdkVersion has to be 8??

Comment: @RenaudFAVIER, I found the id on admob homepage, it was on top right corner. It was pub-something/something.

Comment: @DushyantPatel No, it doesn't have to be. It can be whatever you need.

Comment: @RenaudFAVIER My code compiles and works from API 8 and I can definitely see ads (though I only checked ads on a device on 2.3 which is API 9).

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. I was taking about the minimum SDK. You were right about the target SDK. Very sorry!

Answer (score 0):

see... you first have to download your jar file from admob account for your application then do use the in your project and in Xml file mention that unitId which you have found from this way..
To get your admob ad unit id go to your admob account and click on Sites & Apps and then click the manage button underneath the app you are working with. You'll see the Publisher ID for the app on the details page. This is the Ad Unit ID. copy this to your xml file

Answer (score 0):

after august 1 2014, admob updated the legacy ad nit id, we need to update to latest. Admob ad unit id will be in this format ca-app-pub-XxxXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXX"