# AdMob only displaying Test Banner

Tags: android, admob

I implemented AdMob from https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start?hl=en_US which was running fine as expected during the testing.

[image]

I thought this banner add will be replaced by the actual ads when downloaded from play store, but this doesn't happened !

How to make it happen ?

Am I missing something ?

What should I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the below lines if you have them in your app, it tells admob that the device is used for testing.

```
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
.addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
```

Comment: You only need to remove ``addTestDevice`` if you want to see real ads on **your** device. Everyone else is seeing real ads.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you didn't set "isTesting" to true.

Comment: where is isTesting located